# Need a query help

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

Need a query help. I have a table where data is represented like this

```
userid   TransactionTime           FunctionKey
1018     2011-07-27 09:14:38.000   0
1018     2011-07-27 09:17:11.000   99
1018     2011-07-27 09:38:22.000   0
1018     2011-07-27 10:34:50.000   99
```

I need a query which will return a dataset like this:

```
userid  Intime                  Outtime
1018    2011-07-27 09:14:38.000 2011-07-27 09:17:11.000
1018    2011-07-27 09:38:22.000 2011-07-27 10:34:50.000
```

Please Help..

Comment: when Funtionkey is 0 then its Intime, when it's 99 then its Outtime

Comment: Do you need to deal with 'spurious' data?  (Login and Logout at the same time, login followed by login, logout followed by logout, etc, etc)

Comment: Ya Dems it should be (login followed by login, logout followed by logout, etc, etc) in this way..And I donno why there is a down vote in my question :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @T table (userid int, TransactionTime datetime, FunctionKey int)
insert into @T values
(1018,     '2011-07-27 09:14:38.000',   0),
(1018,     '2011-07-27 09:17:11.000',   99),
(1018,     '2011-07-27 09:38:22.000',   0),
(1018,     '2011-07-27 10:34:50.000',   99),
(1019,     '2011-07-27 09:14:38.000',   0),
(1019,     '2011-07-27 09:17:11.000',   0),
(1019,     '2011-07-27 09:38:22.000',   99),
(1020,     '2011-07-27 09:14:38.000',   0),
(1020,     '2011-07-27 09:17:11.000',   99),
(1020,     '2011-07-27 09:38:22.000',   99)

;with cte as
( 
  select userid,
         TransactionTime,
         FunctionKey,
         row_number() over(partition by userid order by TransactionTime) as rn
  from @T
)
select C1.userid,
       C1.TransactionTime as InTime,
       C2.TransactionTime as OutTime
from cte as C1
  left outer join cte as C2
    on C1.userid = C2.userid and
       C1.rn + 1 = C2.rn
where C1.FunctionKey = 0
```

Result:

```
userid      InTime                  OutTime
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1018        2011-07-27 09:14:38.000 2011-07-27 09:17:11.000
1018        2011-07-27 09:38:22.000 2011-07-27 10:34:50.000
1019        2011-07-27 09:14:38.000 2011-07-27 09:17:11.000
1019        2011-07-27 09:17:11.000 2011-07-27 09:38:22.000
1020        2011-07-27 09:14:38.000 2011-07-27 09:17:11.000
```

Comment: Does assume every logout is immediately preceeded by a login, and a login is never immeditately preceeded by a login.  +1 as OP wasn't explicit on that.

Comment: That will work fine Mikael...But what if two consecutive rows have same FunctionKey value?

Comment: @Tanvir - How do you want to deal with that scenario?  (My answer deals with it one way, another option is to filter out all but the *last* "duplicate" logout and all but the *first* "duplicate" login. Without knowing what you want, we can't give you a cast-iron answer.)

Comment: @Tanvir - You should update your question with sample data that shows your situation and you should specify the the output you want.

Comment: @Tanvir Updated my answer to answer your question. With consecutive 0 it will use the second 0 as a logout **and** as a login. It will omit the timespan between consecutive 99.

Comment: @Mikael & Dems - Thanks a ton for your contribution. I think Mikael's solution can handle the situation well. I just have to ensure that there is no wrong data.

Comment: Note: Still assumes the first record is a login.

Comment: @Dems Not sure what you mean by that. If the first record (for a user) is 99 there is no matching login so that record would not be included. This query uses the first record that is a login and get the out time from the next record regardless of if that record is a login or a logout. That means that a consecutive login is treated as an implicit logout. That could very well be the case when an app crashes.

Comment: @Mikael - I meant just what you said :) If the first record is a logout, it is not included in the results.  In my experience of such data the normal desire is to include it and then infer the login.  For example, if the report is from mid-night, and the first record is a logout, assume the were logged in from mid-night.  Then, a login following a login is treated as both a logout and an immediate re-login, and a logout following a logout is treated as a logout followed by an immediate re-logout.  It all depends, I was just pointing out one implication :)

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH
  ordered AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUNBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY TransactionTime, FunctionKey) item_id,
    *
  FROM
    myTable
)
, logins AS
(
  SELECT * FROM ordered WHERE FunctionKey = 0
)
, logouts AS
(
  SELECT * FROM ordered WHERE FunctionKey = 99
)

SELECT
  COALESCE([logins].userid, [logouts].userid),
  [logins].TransactionTime,
  [logouts].TransactionTime
FROM
  [logins]
FULL OUTER JOIN
  [logouts]
    ON  [logouts].userid      =  [logins].userid
    AND [logouts].item_id     =  [logins].item_id + 1
    AND [logouts].FunctionKey <> [logins].FunctionKey
ORDER BY
  COALESCE([logins].TransactionTime, [logouts].TransactionTime)
```

Alternatively, this one deals with sequences of logins by taking the first login, and sequences of logogut by taking the last logout.

```
WITH
  ordered AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUNBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY TransactionTime, FunctionKey)
    -
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid, FunctionKey ORDER BY TransactionTime)
    AS group_id,
    *
  FROM
    myTable
)
,
  filtered AS
(
  SELECT
    userid,
    FunctionKey,
    CASE WHEN FunctionKey = 0 THEN MIN(TransactionTime) ELSE MAX(TransactionTime) END AS TransactionTime
  FROM
    ordered
  GROUP BY
    userid,
    FunctionKey,
    group_id
)
,
  sequenced AS
(
  SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY TransactionTime, FunctionKey) AS item_id,
   *
  FROM
    filtered
)
, logins AS
(
  SELECT * FROM sequenced WHERE FunctionKey = 0
)
, logouts AS
(
  SELECT * FROM sequenced WHERE FunctionKey = 99
)

SELECT
  COALESCE([logins].userid, [logouts].userid),
  [logins].TransactionTime,
  [logouts].TransactionTime
FROM
  [logins]
FULL OUTER JOIN
  [logouts]
    ON  [logouts].userid      =  [logins].userid
    AND [logouts].item_id     =  [logins].item_id + 1
    AND [logouts].FunctionKey <> [logins].FunctionKey
ORDER BY
  COALESCE([logins].TransactionTime, [logouts].TransactionTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to itself, taking one timestamp from each:

```
select
  t1.userid,
  t1.TransactionTime as InTime
  t2.TransactionTime as Outtime
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t2.userid = t1.userid and t2.FunctionKey = 99
where t1.FunctionKey = 0;
```

Comment: This will match record 1 to records 2 and 4, and record 3 also to records 2 and 4.